# jekyll two different versions of some page

Tags: html, jekyll

Okay, I'm working with jekyll for 3 days now, so I'm stil a huge noob.

I would like to know if something like the following is possible.

I making a game, and I would like to add two different versions of the game. In one version you have acess to all tools, in the other version you have access to only 3 tools.

My page name is LevelX.html and is converted by jekyll to LevelX/index.html

Now I want one version of the game hosted there, and the other version I want to have hosted here: hard/LevelX/index.html

The difference between the two version is only one code of LevelX.html file, the one page should have:

`parameters.customToolBar = "501 | 5 | 15 | 18 | 10 | 100001 | 100002 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 100003 | 53";`

and the page with difficulty hard should have:
`parameters.customToolBar = "501 | 5 | 15`

Is it possible to easily add some line to my LevelX.html file so that jekyll will do exactly this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your config.yml add :

```
#...
parameters:
  customToolBar:
    easy: "501 | 5 | 15 | 18 | 10 | 100001 | 100002 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 100003 | 53"
    hard: "501 | 5 | 15"
```

Create a LevelX.html page

```
---
title: Level X Easy
layout: default
---

{# passing the easy toolbar #}
{% include _levelX.html customToolBar=site.customToolBar.easy %}
```

Create a hard/LevelX.html page

```
---
title: Level X Hard
layout: default
---

{# passing the hard toolbar #}
{% include _levelX.html customToolBar=site.customToolBar.hard %}
```

And finally the include (include/_levelX.html) :

```
{# transform you string to an array #}
{% assign toolBarArray = include.customToolBar | split: "|" %}

<ul>
{% for tool in toolBarArray %}
    <li>{{ tool }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Et voilà !